# How to check the data type exchanged over UDP connection

Tags: java, sockets, udp

Is there a way to determine the data type being exchanged from a client to the server?

Here is a code example of how I think my answer should look like:

```
byte[] dataBook = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packetR = new DatagramPacket(dataBook, dataBook.length);
dS.receive(packetR);

 // the following is psuedo code
 if (packetR.getData() is off data type String) {
      // do code here
 }
if (packetR.getdata() is off data type  File) {
    // do diff code here
}
```

Comment: What format is used to send objects? Is it a standard serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

packet.getData() returns an array of bytes. It is up to you to interpret it. 
Basically, your server needs to know something about the method client uses to encode its data as bytes. For example (not necessarily the best option), you could use java serialization protocol:
On the client:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bytes);
os.writeObject(messageToSend);
os.close();
datagramPacket.setData(bytes.toByteArray());
socket.send(datagramPacket);
```

Then, on the server:

```
byte bytes[] = datagramPacket.getData();
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
Serializable messageReceived = is.readObject();
if(messageReceived instanceof String) {
    handleString((String) messageReceived);
}
else {
   // etc.
}
```

You may find some information [in this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html) helpful.